# Custom styled ListBox with several strings

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listbox

I'm working on a VB project and I need some help with `ListBox`.

I need to create a `ListBox` which is populated by some data from a database. An alternative is of course `DataGridView`, but that's not what I want. I want to style my `ListBox` to output several strings from my database:

- A title header
- An icon
- And some other sub-headings

This picture kind of demonstrates how I want it to look:

[image]

I have looked a bit into WPF, but I'm not sure how it's used with VB. This is a project for a VB-class I'm taking, so it's kind of mandatory that it is VB.

Comment: Look at the DrawMode property and set it to OwnerDrawFixed.  Set the ItemHeight to something like 32.  Then use the DrawItem event to draw your stuff.  If nothing else, those are easily searchable items for you.

Comment: "sub headings" (groups?) can be done but is pretty involved.  Even using DrawMode is probably more than was intended in the class, explore CodeProject for several owner draw listboxes.  However, based on some of what you wrote, consider a ListView instead (icons and groups headers are built in)